# How to use Map or semVerMap in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have these three lines of code and Im trying to use semVerMap like this-

```
def ccsmpVersionsInfo = readFile 'tools/versions.properties'
ccsmpVersionsInfo["version.release"] = semVerMap(ccsmpVersionsInfo, "version", ".")
String deployVersion = ccsmpVersionsInfo["version.release"]
```

But I get this error-

```
No such DSL method 'semVerMap' found among steps
```

I was wondering if I can use something else instead of "semVerMap" to do the same thing.

could you please help me with this. Any suggestions on what I can do are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `semVerMap` defined in a plugin, library, or elsewhere in the pipeline?

Comment: As far as I know `semVerMap`  is a part of some pipeline plugin, but even in this case, I cant install new plugins on my Jenkins, So I thought if I could use something else that full fills its function in some way

Comment: Could you please describe the expected functionality for the `semVerMap` method, or otherwise link to some documentation?

Comment: so semver basically is used for Semantic Versioning , Here are some good documentation on it- 

[link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver) 

[link](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/semantic-versioning#:~:text=SemVer%20is%20a%20popular%20versioning,interpret%20a%20specific%20version%20change)

Comment: So you want to port the functionality of a Node.js package to Jenkins Pipeline. You probably want to start with https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/. If you hit a roadblock, then feel free to ask a question here on SO for further assistance.